# Powerpoint - import Flash with XML

Tags: xml, flash, powerpoint

I'm working with an interactive map in Flash, and its importation into 
Powerpoint.

Once the map is placed, countries link to XML data in another file and 
display location names, tables with data etc.

When I first place the flash file in PPT, it works fine. When I exit the 
program, the Powerpoint file ceases to draw upon the XML data.

I'm using Powerpoint 2007, and all files are saved to the same directory.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you have to use LiveWeb addon in PowerPoint and place a HTML file with embedded flash file into a presentation.

Comment: Link to LiveWeb addon: http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm#.UIktzYZdDA4